# Laravel Auth User

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

In my controller i'm doing

```
$user = Auth:user()->get();
dd($user);
```

This is giving me the list of **all** users from my database.
why?

Comment: just remove `->get();`

Answer (score 4):

The other answers either explain how to solve your problem but not properly why this happens.

The laravel documentation states ([source](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#retrieving-results)):

> The `get` method returns an `Illuminate\Support\Collection` containing the results where each result is an instance of the PHP `StdClass` object.

With the full documentation found [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/collections#method-get), with API references [here](https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_get).

In essence, the `get` function here returns a collection and not the `User` object. The get method on an `QueryBuilder` executes a select statement.

With the following snippet we can see what queries get executed.

```
DB::enableQueryLog();
Auth::user()->get();
dump(DB::getQueryLog());
```

This will output: [image: Only get output]

```
DB::enableQueryLog();
Auth::user()->where('id', 1)->get();
dump(DB::getQueryLog());
```

This will output: [image: Get with where output]

The first query will indeed output the expected user, the second query will grab the user class from the `Auth::user()` and select all rows from that table.

When we execute the 3rd and 4th query we can see that we once more first get the expected user, the 4th query however does also get a user (in this case the user with id 1). This is due too the `where` and not the `Auth::user()`.

What we can conclude from these results is that the get takes into account all query builder functions but not the parameters of the supplied class.
If you use a get on an object it will only take into account the Class of that Object.

As too solve your problem the other questions where correct and you can use:

```
$user = Auth::user();
```

To fetch the user.

Answer (score 0):

Because get return collection

[Laravel Doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-collections)

Answer (score 0):

Just remove **get()** to get single user data

```
$user = Auth:user();
dd($user);
```

in this case **get()** method return user collection object

Answer (score 0):

You can auth user data by :

```
$user = Auth::user(); instead of using get();

 Your user id is: {{ $user->id }}
    Your first name is: {{ $user->first_name }}
    Your last name is: {{ $user->last_name }}
```

Comment: Although your question does solve the answer it does not give any explanation as too why this is the case (which was specifically asked for in the question)

Answer (score 0):

return User::where('id', auth()->id())->with(['something'])->first()